# Android - Read first 2 lines of String

Tags: java, android, string, int

I have a large String (let's call it `c`), which looks like this:

---

```
12345
67890
some
random
data
```

---

There's two variables - `int a` and `int b`.
I need to read the first line from `c` and put it's value to `a`, and read the second line from `c` and put it's value to `b`. How I can do that?

**UPD** I think it is not a good way to use String[]. `c` is VERY large String, and `split()` method can freeze my app. Is there an another way to do the trick?

P.S. Excuse for my English, please.

Comment: Do you always want the first and second? Then you can run a simple loop and get them..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare, how I can do that loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say your string is `c` which has the above value separated by `linebreak`

Use the following code:

```
String lines[] = c.split("\\r?\\n");
int a = Integer.parse(lines[0]);
int b = Integer.parse(lines[1]);
```

**Update**

Here is an alternate loop that you can use to get the first and second lines:

```
boolean found = false;
int position = 0, oldPosition = 0;
int a, b, count = 0;

while(!found) {
    if(c.charAt(position) == '\n') {
        count++;
        if(count == 1) {
            a = Integer.parseInt(c.substring(oldPosition, position));
            oldPosition = position+1;
        }
        if(count == 2) {
            b = Integer.parseInt(c.substring(oldPosition, position));
            found = true;
        }
    }
    position++;
}
```